# Scheduling Alexa Sounds with a Skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

If I want to make a custom to play a certain sound at a certain time every day, for example an alarm clock. Is this possible with the current Alexa skill API? I cannot find any documentation on it.

(I realize I can already ask Alexa to wake me up but I want to be a bit more custom)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. With regards to scheduling all you can do is use [notifications](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/833b9af4-26e6-47d2-a13d-bdbd9a257512/expanded-developer-preview-of-notifications-for-alexa-skills). The user gets a generic notification sound and can ask "What did I miss?" then all queued notifications (from all skills that the user has enabled and pushed notifications) will be read by Alexa.